# Возможно ли кастомизировать web-интерфейс роутера?

Tags: роутер, декомпиляция, прошивка

Скачал бинарный файл прошивки роутера. Хотелось бы изменить цвет текста и фон в web-конфигураторе. Скачал HEX редактор и ничего там не понял. Сколько бы я не бился декодировать 16-ричную систему в понятный язык, из читаемого только первые несколько строк, где написана модель и ядро. Какую строку изменить и куда залить файл с фоном не понятно, хоть убей. Так вот, стоит ли дальше долбиться в эту кирпичную стену или стоит отказаться от этой идеи, и всё это во власти разработчиков прошивки? Также, интересен сам процесс разработки прошивки. Если кто опишет, будет круто. Upd: Роутер RT-GM-3 1.6.918

Comment: Можно через плагины браузера вносить изменения на странице. Я пользуюсь stylus, удобно

Comment: Я с этим методом знаком, удобно, конечно. В моём случае, очень часто приходится заходить на роутер не только с моего личного ПК, но и с других, а также с мобильных устройств. Хотелось бы везде иметь одинаковый вид. Правда, с кем не общался из владельцев данного роутера, но прошивка там вырвиглазная